# Html Table Export plugin not working not showing view table data export

Tags: plugins, highcharts

I want to show View data in html table using export  and I am using v4 exporting .js and it is not exporting view table data so what should I do in v4 exporting .js  and if  I use  latest JavaScript  it also not showing but when I use locally it works fine and view data table plugin is showing

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You need to show us some code for anyone to help

Comment: Hi @ankit jangid, Please describe your problem more precisely and add some live example. You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: i paste my code in js fiddle  this code is working fine when i run on localhost but when i put this code on server then html table   option and the table is not showing because exporting module release in version 8 and my Admin Panel use V4 exporting  Module  so how can  i achieve this thing using version 4 script or without script file, how can i show the html table with or without script file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fk5q4hn0/1/

Comment: Yes, you are right - that functionality is not available in version 4. You need to create it by yourself with some custom code. You can take an example from the `getTable` method from source code: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.src.js

Comment: i am not able to do that i mean i am still confused can you provide me the exact ode so that i can do it as fast as i can

Comment: provide me a code so that i can use it in my code

Comment: I can help you with implementation, but I can't just provide you with the whole code.

Comment: okay no problem i don't need the code i want only implementation steps